# How can I create an ext4 ramdisk?

Tags: mount, ext4, tmpfs, ramdisk

First, I have create the directory that I will want to mount to.

`mkdir /mnt/ramdisk`

Now, I could easily turn this into a ramdisk using ramfs or tmpfs via

`mount -t tmpfs -o size=512m tmpfs /mnt/ramdisk`

I've found a [tutorial on how to create a ramdisk](https://www.jamescoyle.net/how-to/943-create-a-ram-disk-in-linux) which breaks this syntax down as:

`mount -t [TYPE] -o size=[SIZE] [FSTYPE] [MOUNTPOINT]`

The tutorial indicates that I can replace [FSTYPE] with ext4 to change the FS to ext4.  However, I am not convinced this method is correct and that the author has misjudged what changing the [FSTYPE] argument actually does.

**UPDATE:** For those interested, G-Man and Johan Myréen have weighed in on my speculations about [FSTYPE].  Essentially, the [FSTYPE] argument acts as a necessary (but ignored) placeholder used by `mount`.  See this post's comments for more details.

I would like to know the proper way to create an ext4 ramdisk.  That is, I want a temporary directory in memory that uses the ext4 file system.  How can this be achieved?

Comment: I believe that the `mount -t [TYPE] -o size=[SIZE] [FSTYPE] [MOUNTPOINT]` command is correct, with the constraint that `[TYPE]` must be either **tmpfs** or **ramfs**.  I doubt that it is possible to do what you’re asking (but Ipor’s answer presents an interesting workaround).

Comment: @G-Man The reason I am suspicious is because [FSTYPE] can be set to any value.  For example, I was able to run `mount -t tmpfs -o size=512m ext433 /mnt/ramdisk` with no issue.  Checking `df -Th` reported that the Filesystem at `/mnt/ramdisk` was `ext433` with type `tmpfs`, which I do not understand.

Comment: The [RAM disk block device](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/blockdev/ramdisk.txt) might be more appropriate...

Comment: Good point!  It might not be clear (since [James Coyle](https://www.jamescoyle.net/how-to/943-create-a-ram-disk-in-linux) made no effort to explain it) that the command ``mount -t tmpfs -o size=512m tmpfs /mnt/ramdisk`` consists of five pieces: `mount`, `-t tmpfs`, `-o size=512m`, `tmpfs` and `/mnt/ramdisk` — the second `tmpfs` doesn’t go with the `-o`.  And the basic `mount` syntax is `mount ` *`device  dir`*,  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  so you’re right — the penultimate argument isn’t really `[FSTYPE]`, but rather *`device`* (i.e., the analog of `/dev/sda1`).  And, according to [How to correctly mount a tmpfs?](https://superuser.com/q/847469/354511), when you have `-t tmpfs`, the *`device`* is just a placeholder, and not interpreted (but, apparently, it is stored, and subsequently reported by `df`).  (I suspect the same is true for `-t ramfs`.)  So I agree with you that [James Coyle’s tutorial](https://www.jamescoyle.net/how-to/943-create-a-ram-disk-in-linux) is misleading. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Which makes me all the more confident that it’s impossible to specify a filesystem type for a RAM disk. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … …  Additional interesting note: [mount(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html) says that ``-o size=512m`` is valid only with `-t tmpfs`, and is ignored for `ramfs`).

Comment: The `FSTYPE` field must be present to get enough command parameters so that the `mount` program interprets we are doing a "manual" mount, i.e. it should not look up `/mnt/ramdisk` in `/etc/fstab`. It can be anything, and the value is ignored for tmpfs.

Comment: @buratino I'm curious what you are trying to achive. The point of both Ramfs and Tmpfs is to provide storage with an interface that looks like a file system, without using a storage media structure like Ext4, because Ramfs and Tmpfs don't need one. The older RAM disk block device (`/dev/ram0`) Stephen Kitt mentioned works more like a traditional disk-based device in that an area of RAM is reserved which acts like a block device on which you can create any file system with `mkfs`. Ramfs and Tmpfs provide a smarter way to store files in RAM.

Comment: @JohanMyréen I'm looking at how ext4 function latencies are affected by having the functions invoked in memory and out of memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have combined an idea given to me by Ipor Sircer's answer with Stephen Kitt's suggestion of using a [RAM disk block device](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/blockdev/ramdisk.txt).

First, I compiled `CONFIG_BLK_DEV_RAM` into my kernel.  I changed the default number of RAM disks from 16 to 8 (`BLK_DEV_RAM_COUNT`), though that is based on preference and not necessity.

Next, I created the folder I want to mount to.

`mkdir /mnt/ext4ramdisk`

Finally, I formatted my RAM disk block device with ext4 and mounted it.

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/ram0
mount -t ext4 /dev/ram0 /mnt/ext4ramdisk
```

Answer (score 8):

```
mkdir /mnt/ramdisk
mount -t ramfs ramfs /mnt/ramdisk
dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/ramdisk/ext4.image bs=1M count=512
mkfs.ext4 /mnt/ramdisk/ext4.image
mkdir /mnt/ext4ramdisk
mount -o loop /mnt/ramdisk/ext4.image /mnt/ext4ramdisk
```

But remember, ext4 was not designed to use in ram! `tmpfs` and `ramfs` are always better choice in ram than any disk-based filesystem.

Comment: I am aware that tmpfs and ramfs are better choices to be used in ram.  Could you please clarify exactly what is happening the the last three lines of your answer?  Also, if I were to use your solution, how can I verify that /mnt/ext4ramdisk is indeed using ext4?

Comment: The last lines create 1. a big file filled with zeroes on the ramfs, 2. creates an Ext4 filesystem using the file as storage, 3. creates the directory `/mnt/ext4ramdisk` outside the ramfs, 4. loop mounts the image file on `/mnt/ext4ramdisk`.